# Is being perfectoid a local property?

Tags: rigid-analytic-geometry, perfectoid-spaces

In his 2012 CDM proceedings, Peter Scholze mentions the following open question:

Let $K$ be a perfectoid field and $(A,A^+)$ a complete affinoid $K$-algebra. Suppose there exists a cover of $X = \text{Spa}(A,A^+)$ by rational subsets $U_i \subset X$ such that $\mathcal{O}_X(U_i)$ is a perfectoid $K$-algebra. Does it follow that $A$ is a perfectoid $K$-algebra?

Has there been any progress on this question since then?

Comment: I'm not sure about the most current status of this, but for a start you can look at Buzzard & Verberkmoes "Stably Uniform Affinoids are Sheafy", where they prove the result if $A$ is stably uniform and of characteristic $p$.

Comment: This is still an open problem.